# Reference between a form and a user control infinite loop c#

Tags: c#, forms, reference, user-controls

I have a Form and a User Control. Both have to reference to each other because I need to refer in my Form to controls in my User Control and I need to refer in my User Control to controls in my Form. The Form and the User Control have to be linked to each other. I know that I created an infinite loop with the code below. What do I have to do to make sure that the Form and the User Control are refering to each other without creating an infinite loop?

Code in my Form

```
public partial class frmDamageRiskCalculation : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
{
    private FreshSaltWater FSW = new FreshSaltWater();
```

Code in my User Control

```
public partial class FreshSaltWater : UserControl
{
    private frmDamageRiskCalculation fDRC = new frmDamageRiskCalculation(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that this cross reference is mandatory in your code (think hard about that, we can usually avoid it), what you want is an intermediate object to manage the Relationship, as explain in this answer:
[How to cross-reference objects in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393101/how-to-cross-reference-objects-in-classes)